# Calculate the pay percentage for each employee based on pay and pay type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with calculating the pay percentage for each employee based on paytype and pay period

I have data like below

```
ID  date               type         gw  
359 2015-03-28          R           1563.79     
359 2015-04-04          M           11.41       
359 2015-04-04          R           1563.79     
359 2015-04-11          M           11.41       
359 2015-04-11          R           1563.79     
359 2015-04-18          M           11.41       
795 2018-01-12          C           2382.39     
795 2018-01-12          M           3.72        
795 2018-01-12          R           3269.23     
795 2018-01-26          C           1437.74     
795 2018-01-26          M           3.72        
795 2018-01-26          R           3269.23
```

When I run the below query I have result as follows

```
select id,date,type,gw,payPercentage=SUM(gw) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(gw)) OVER ()
from pw_part
where id in ('359',795)
group by ssn,client_id,date,type,gw
```

```
ID  date                type         gw         payPercentage
359 2015-03-28          R           1563.79         0.133187
359 2015-04-04          M           11.41           0.000971
359 2015-04-04          R           1563.79         0.133187
359 2015-04-11          M           11.41           0.000971
359 2015-04-11          R           1563.79         0.133187
359 2015-04-18          M           11.41           0.000971
795 2018-01-12          C           2382.39         0.891623
795 2018-01-12          M           3.72            0.001392
795 2018-01-12          R           3269.23         1.223528
795 2018-01-26          C           1437.74         0.538082
795 2018-01-26          M           3.72            0.001392
795 2018-01-26          R           3269.23         1.223528
```

---

My desired result should be

```
ID  date                type        gw          payPercentage
359 2015-03-28          R           1563.79         100
359 2015-04-04          M           11.41          .72            
359 2015-04-04          R           1563.79         99.27         
359 2015-04-11          M           11.41           .72           
359 2015-04-11          R           1563.79         99.27         
359 2015-04-18          M           11.41           100
795 2018-01-12          C           2382.39         42.12         
795 2018-01-12          M           3.72            .06           
795 2018-01-12          R           3269.23         57.80         
795 2018-01-26          C           1437.74         30.52         
795 2018-01-26          M           3.72            .07           
795 2018-01-26          R           3269.23         69.4
```

How do I get desired result?

Please note: I have millions of ID's and hundreds of dates, here I provided 2 ID's as example to simplify

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want the sums to add up per day (presumably for each id as well).  That would be:

```
select p.*,
       gw * 100.0 / sum(gw) over (partition by id, date) as pay_percentage
from pw_part p;
```

Comment: awesome, thank you my friend.. that worked... Made my day...